# Cloud you help me to describe How recursive program thinking ? (step by step)

Tags: java, recursion

As I study recursive algorithms that code below:

```
    String n = starString(3);
    System.out.print(n);
} public static String starString(int n){
if(n < 0) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}else if(n == 0) {
    return "*";
}else{
    return starString(n - 1) + starString(n - 1);
}
```

I think code will working look like below

```
String n = starString(3); //Value is 3 then send 3 to function
```

so it goes to the `else` condition 3 times, right?

```
starString(3 - 1) + starString(3 - 1); //Its return is "**"

starString(2 - 1) + starString(2 - 1); //Its return is "**"

starString(1 - 1) + starString(1 - 1); //Its return is "**"
```

I think that the result should look like this --> `****** //6 items`

but the program shows the following instead --> `******** //8 items`

Can someone clarify why this is?

Comment: When you do `startString(3)` it call 2 times `startString(2)`, and each will call two times `startString(1)` resulting in calling 4 times `startString(1)` each one printing 2 stars => 8 stars

Answer (score 2):

When you call `starString(3)`, it returns:

```
starString(2) + starString(2)
```

The above expression expands to become (this is where you got it wrong):

```
(starString(1) + starString(1)) + (starString(1) + starString(1))
```

Then each of those calls expand to become:

```
((starString(0) + starString(0)) + (starString(0) + starString(0))) + ((starString(0) + starString(0)) + (starString(0) + starString(0)))
```

Here's a formatted version of the above:

```
(
    (starString(0) + starString(0))
    + 
    (starString(0) + starString(0))
) 
+ 
(
    (starString(0) + starString(0)) 
    +
    (starString(0) + starString(0))
)
```

The outer most bracket is the `starString(2)` call. The inner bracket is the `starString(1)` call.

As you can see, there are 8 calls to `starString`, so 8 `*`s.